# Where can I read the works of Bellamkonda Ramaraya Kavindrulu online?

Tags: vedanta, advaita, vishishtadvaita

Bellamkonda Ramaraya Kavindrulu was a Vishishtadvaitin turned Advaitin and he is said to have refuted the interpretations of Sri Bhashyam of Ramanujacharya especially in his works "***Sankara Sankara Bhasya Vimarsha***" and "***Siddhanta Sindhu***". Where  can I read those works online in English?

Comment: Ramaraya works are not translated into English. His works were translated into Telugu by Mellacheruvu Subrahmanya Sastri but even those works are not digitized.

Comment: @The Destroyer have you ever read his works?